# QSortFilterProxyModel with dates and sqlite

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have reimplemented this example on PyQt5 almost verbatim. The problem in this example is: it assumes you are entering a QDate in the model, but in my case the model is taken from an sqlite DB therefore dates are only text.

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QDate, QDateTime, QRegExp, QSortFilterProxyModel, Qt,
                          QTime)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QComboBox, QDateEdit,
                             QGridLayout, QGroupBox, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit, QTreeView,
                             QVBoxLayout, QWidget,QTableView)


class MySortFilterProxyModel(QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MySortFilterProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)

        self.minDate = QDate()
        self.maxDate = QDate()

    def setFilterMinimumDate(self, date):
        self.minDate = date
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterMinimumDate(self):
        return self.minDate

    def setFilterMaximumDate(self, date):
        self.maxDate = date
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterMaximumDate(self):
        return self.maxDate

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        index0 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent)
        index1 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 1, sourceParent)
        index2 = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, 2, sourceParent)


        return ((self.filterRegExp().indexIn(self.sourceModel().data(index0)) >= 0
                 or self.filterRegExp().indexIn(self.sourceModel().data(index1)) >= 0)
                and self.dateInRange(self.sourceModel().data(index2)))

    def dateInRange(self, date):
        if isinstance(date, QDateTime):
            date = date.date()

        return ((not self.minDate.isValid() or date >= self.minDate)
                and (not self.maxDate.isValid() or date <= self.maxDate))


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.proxyModel = MySortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxyModel.setDynamicSortFilter(True)

        self.sourceView = QTreeView()
        self.sourceView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.sourceView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        sourceLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        sourceLayout.addWidget(self.sourceView)
        sourceGroupBox = QGroupBox("Original Model")
        sourceGroupBox.setLayout(sourceLayout)

        self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox = QCheckBox("Case sensitive filter")
        self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox.setChecked(True)
        self.filterPatternLineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.filterPatternLineEdit.setText("Grace|Sports")
        filterPatternLabel = QLabel("&Filter pattern:")
        filterPatternLabel.setBuddy(self.filterPatternLineEdit)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox = QComboBox()
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.addItem("Regular expression", QRegExp.RegExp)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.addItem("Wildcard", QRegExp.Wildcard)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.addItem("Fixed string", QRegExp.FixedString)
        self.fromDateEdit = QDateEdit()
        self.fromDateEdit.setDate(QDate(2006, 12, 22))
        self.fromDateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        fromLabel = QLabel("F&rom:")
        fromLabel.setBuddy(self.fromDateEdit)
        self.toDateEdit = QDateEdit()
        self.toDateEdit.setDate(QDate(2007, 1, 5))
        self.toDateEdit.setCalendarPopup(True)
        toLabel = QLabel("&To:")
        toLabel.setBuddy(self.toDateEdit)

        self.filterPatternLineEdit.textChanged.connect(self.textFilterChanged)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.textFilterChanged)
        self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox.toggled.connect(self.textFilterChanged)
        self.fromDateEdit.dateChanged.connect(self.dateFilterChanged)
        self.toDateEdit.dateChanged.connect(self.dateFilterChanged)

        self.proxyView = QTableView()
        # self.proxyView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        self.proxyView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)
        self.proxyView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.proxyView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        self.proxyView.sortByColumn(1, Qt.AscendingOrder)

        self.textFilterChanged()
        self.dateFilterChanged()

        proxyLayout = QGridLayout()
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.proxyView, 0, 0, 1, 3)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(filterPatternLabel, 1, 0)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.filterPatternLineEdit, 1, 1)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.filterSyntaxComboBox, 1, 2)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox, 2, 0, 1, 3)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(fromLabel, 3, 0)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.fromDateEdit, 3, 1, 1, 2)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(toLabel, 4, 0)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.toDateEdit, 4, 1, 1, 2)
        proxyGroupBox = QGroupBox("Sorted/Filtered Model")
        proxyGroupBox.setLayout(proxyLayout)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(sourceGroupBox)
        mainLayout.addWidget(proxyGroupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Custom Sort/Filter Model")
        self.resize(500, 450)

    def setSourceModel(self, model):
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(model)
        self.sourceView.setModel(model)

    def textFilterChanged(self):
        syntax = QRegExp.PatternSyntax(
            self.filterSyntaxComboBox.itemData(
                self.filterSyntaxComboBox.currentIndex()))
        caseSensitivity = (
                self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox.isChecked()
                and Qt.CaseSensitive or Qt.CaseInsensitive)
        regExp = QRegExp(self.filterPatternLineEdit.text(), caseSensitivity, syntax)
        self.proxyModel.setFilterRegExp(regExp)

    def dateFilterChanged(self):
        self.proxyModel.setFilterMinimumDate(self.fromDateEdit.date())
        self.proxyModel.setFilterMaximumDate(self.toDateEdit.date())


    def addMail(model, subject, sender, date):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 0), subject)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 1), sender)
        model.setData(model.index(0, 2), date)


def createMailModel(parent):
    model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3, parent)

    model.setHeaderData(0, Qt.Horizontal, "Subject")
    model.setHeaderData(1, Qt.Horizontal, "Sender")
    model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, "Date")

    addMail(model, "Happy New Year!", "Grace K. <grace@software-inc.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2006, 12, 31), QTime(17, 3)))
    addMail(model, "Radically new concept", "Grace K. <grace@software-inc.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2006, 12, 22), QTime(9, 44)))
    addMail(model, "Accounts", "pascale@nospam.com",
            QDateTime(QDate(2006, 12, 31), QTime(12, 50)))
    addMail(model, "Expenses", "Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2006, 12, 25), QTime(11, 39)))
    addMail(model, "Re: Expenses", "Andy <andy@nospam.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2007, 1, 2), QTime(16, 5)))
    addMail(model, "Re: Accounts", "Joe Bloggs <joe@bloggs.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2007, 1, 3), QTime(14, 18)))
    addMail(model, "Re: Accounts", "Andy <andy@nospam.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2007, 1, 3), QTime(14, 26)))
    addMail(model, "Sports", "Linda Smith <linda.smith@nospam.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2007, 1, 5), QTime(11, 33)))
    addMail(model, "AW: Sports", "Rolf Newschweinstein <rolfn@nospam.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2007, 1, 5), QTime(12, 0)))
    addMail(model, "RE: Sports", "Petra Schmidt <petras@nospam.com>",
            QDateTime(QDate(2007, 1, 5), QTime(12, 1)))

    return model


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = Window()
    window.setSourceModel(createMailModel(window))
    window.show()        
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've tried to change this line:`self.dateInRange(self.sourceModel().data(index2)))` to this:`self.dateInRange(datetime.strptime(self.sourceModel().data(index2),"%Y/%m/%d %H:%M")))` in order to convert the data TXT to the format date and this works well for filtering but crashes if I add a new row to the DB using:

```
@pyqtSlot()
def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
    self.add_record()

def add_record(self):
    row = self.db_model.rowCount()
    self.db_model.insertRow(row)
```

Where am I going wrong?

Relevant DB part:

```
class essaiFindDb():
    def __init__(self):
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName("essai_find_database.db")

        self.db.open()

        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.exec_('''CREATE TABLE Pilots_exp(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE , pilot_1 TEXT,aircraft TEXT, date_time1 TEXT, date_time2 TEXT, total TEXT)''')
```

Comment: share your .db ....

Comment: You say:  *but in my case the model is taken from an sqlite DB therefore dates are only text*, I do not see that part in your [mcve] why can not you share the .db?

Comment: in your initial example there is only one QDateTime, but with the code that you create your table I can think that there are 2 could you explain better if there are differences?

Comment: Hi @eyllanesc, I've tried the Minimal, complete example but failed the Verifiable part .I'll try to do better next time, thanks  for the answer below it is precisly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analyzing the problem is impossible since you have not provided an MCVE.

So my solution will be based on what you point out:

- Columns 3(date_time1) and 4(date_time2) have the date format.
- The date format is `%Y/%m/%d %H:%M`(python datetime format)- `yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm`(Qt format)
- The date filter is applied to column 3.

As you've noticed, the simplest thing would be if column 3 and 4 were QDateTime, so I'll create a proxy to do the conversion.

On the other hand I have separated the filter into time filters and text filters to have clearer codes.

In this case I will apply the cascading proxies:

```
┌-----------------┐    ┌---------------------------┐    ┌------------------------┐    ┌------------------------┐
|    db_model     | -> |     text_to_QDateTime     | -> |       filter_date      | -> |       filter_text      |
|(QSqlTableModel) |    | (ConvertToDateProxyModel) |    | (FilterDateProxyModel) |    | (FilterTextProxyModel) |
└-----------------┘    └---------------------------┘    └------------------------┘    └------------------------┘
```

Considering the above, the solution is:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql 

def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('essai_find_database.db')
    if not db.open():
        QtWidgets.QMessageBox.critical(None, QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Cannot open database"),
                             QtWidgets.qApp.tr("Unable to establish a database connection.\n"
                                     "This example needs SQLite support. Please read "
                                     "the Qt SQL driver documentation for information "
                                     "how to build it.\n\n"
                                     "Click Cancel to exit."),
                            QtWidgets.QMessageBox.Cancel)
        return False

    query = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    return query.exec_('''
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Pilots_exp ( 
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE ,
            pilot_1 TEXT,aircraft TEXT, 
            date_time1 TEXT, date_time2 TEXT, 
            total TEXT)
        ''')

class ConvertToDateProxyModel(QtCore.QIdentityProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ConvertToDateProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = []
        self._fmt = ""

    def set_format(self, fmt):
        self._fmt = fmt

    def set_columns(self, columns):
        self._columns = columns

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        v = super(ConvertToDateProxyModel, self).data(index, role)
        if not index.isValid():
            return
        if index.column() in self._columns and self._fmt:
            return QtCore.QDateTime.fromString(v, self._fmt)
        return v

    def setData(self, index, value, role=QtCore.Qt.EditRole):
        if index.column() in self._columns and self._fmt:
            sm = self.sourceModel()
            ix = self.mapToSource(index)
            return sm.setData(ix, value.toString(self._fmt), role)
        return super(ConvertToDateProxyModel, self).setData(index, value, role)

class FilterDateProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FilterDateProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._from_date, self._to_date = QtCore.QDate(), QtCore.QDate()

    def setRange(self, from_date, to_date):
        self._from_date = from_date
        self._to_date = to_date
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if any([not date.isValid() for date in (self._from_date, self._to_date,)]):
            return True
        ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, self.filterKeyColumn(), sourceParent)
        dt = ix.data().date()
        return self._from_date <= dt <= self._to_date

class FilterTextProxyModel(QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(FilterTextProxyModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._columns = []

    def set_columns(self, columns):
        self._columns = columns
        self.invalidateFilter()

    def filterAcceptsRow(self, sourceRow, sourceParent):
        if not self._columns:
            return True
        values = []
        for c in range(self.sourceModel().columnCount()):
            if c in self._columns:
                ix = self.sourceModel().index(sourceRow, c, sourceParent)
                values.append(self.filterRegExp().indexIn(ix.data()) >= 0)
        return any(values)


class AddDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, formats, parent=None):
        super(AddDialog, self).__init__(parent)
        self._editors = dict()
        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self)
        for key, value in formats.items():
            editor = self.create_editor_by_type(value)
            flay.addRow(key, editor)
            self._editors[key] = editor

        buttonBox = QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox()
        buttonBox.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        buttonBox.setStandardButtons(QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel|QtWidgets.QDialogButtonBox.Ok)

        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        flay.addRow(buttonBox)

    def create_editor_by_type(self, t):
        editor = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        if t == QtCore.QDateTime:
            editor = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit(
                dateTime= QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime(),
                displayFormat="yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm",
                calendarPopup=True
            )
        return editor

    def get_value_from_editor(self, editor):
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QLineEdit):
            return editor.text()
        if isinstance(editor, QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit):
            return editor.dateTime()

    def get_values(self):
        result = dict()
        for key, editor in self._editors.items():
            result[key] = self.get_value_from_editor(editor)
        return result

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.db_model = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(self)
        self.db_model.setTable("Pilots_exp")
        self.db_model.select()

        proxy_convert_to_date = ConvertToDateProxyModel(self)
        proxy_convert_to_date.setSourceModel(self.db_model)
        proxy_convert_to_date.set_columns([3, 4])
        proxy_convert_to_date.set_format("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm")

        sourceGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Original Model")
        sourceView = QtWidgets.QTableView(alternatingRowColors=True)
        sourceView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        sourceView.verticalHeader().hide()
        sourceView.setModel(proxy_convert_to_date)
        sourceLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(sourceGroupBox)
        sourceLayout.addWidget(sourceView)

        self._proxy_date = FilterDateProxyModel(self)
        self._proxy_date.setFilterKeyColumn(3)
        self._proxy_date.setSourceModel(proxy_convert_to_date)

        self._proxy_filter = FilterTextProxyModel(self)
        self._proxy_filter.setSourceModel(self._proxy_date)
        self._proxy_filter.set_columns([1, 2])

        proxyGroupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Sorted/Filtered Model")
        proxyView = QtWidgets.QTableView()
        proxyView.verticalHeader().hide()
        proxyView.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QtWidgets.QHeaderView.Stretch)
        proxyView.setSortingEnabled(True)
        proxyView.setModel(self._proxy_filter)
        proxyView.sortByColumn(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        proxyLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(proxyGroupBox)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(proxyView)

        filterPatternLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel("&Filter pattern:")
        self.filterPatternLineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(
            "Grace|Sports",
            textChanged=self.update_filter_text
        )
        filterPatternLabel.setBuddy(self.filterPatternLineEdit)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox = QtWidgets.QComboBox(
            currentIndexChanged=self.update_filter_text
        )

        self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(
            "Case sensitive filter", 
            checked=True,
            stateChanged=self.update_filter_text
        )
        self.fromDateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(
            calendarPopup=True, 
            date=QtCore.QDate(2006, 12, 22),
            dateChanged=self.update_filter_date
        )
        self.toDateEdit = QtWidgets.QDateEdit(
            calendarPopup=True, 
            date=QtCore.QDate(2007, 1, 5),
            dateChanged=self.update_filter_date
        )

        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.addItem("Regular expression", QtCore.QRegExp.RegExp)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.addItem("Wildcard", QtCore.QRegExp.Wildcard)
        self.filterSyntaxComboBox.addItem("Fixed string", QtCore.QRegExp.FixedString)
        self.update_filter_text()
        self.update_filter_date()

        flay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
        flay.addRow("F&rom:", self.fromDateEdit)
        flay.addRow("&To:", self.toDateEdit)

        hlay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        hlay.addWidget(filterPatternLabel)
        hlay.addWidget(self.filterPatternLineEdit)
        hlay.addWidget(self.filterSyntaxComboBox)
        proxyLayout.addWidget(self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox)
        proxyLayout.addLayout(hlay)
        proxyLayout.addLayout(flay)

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(sourceGroupBox)
        lay.addWidget(proxyGroupBox)

        proxyView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        proxyView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.on_customContextMenuRequested)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QPoint)
    def on_customContextMenuRequested(self, p):
        view = self.sender()
        menu = QtWidgets.QMenu()
        add_row_action = menu.addAction("Add Row")
        action = menu.exec_(view.viewport().mapToGlobal(p))
        if action == add_row_action:
            self.add_record()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_filter_text(self):
        syntax = self.filterSyntaxComboBox.currentData()
        caseSensitivity = QtCore.Qt.CaseSensitive \
            if self.filterCaseSensitivityCheckBox.isChecked() \
            else QtCore.Qt.CaseInsensitive
        regExp = QtCore.QRegExp(self.filterPatternLineEdit.text(), caseSensitivity, syntax)
        self._proxy_filter.setFilterRegExp(regExp)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def update_filter_date(self):
        self._proxy_date.setRange(self.fromDateEdit.date(), self.toDateEdit.date())

    def add_record(self):
        d = {}
        rec = self.db_model.record()
        for i in range(rec.count()):
            d[rec.fieldName(i)] = type(rec.value(i))

        for i in (3, 4): d[rec.fieldName(i)] = QtCore.QDateTime

        del d[rec.fieldName(0)]

        dialog = AddDialog(d, self)
        if dialog.exec_() == QtWidgets.QDialog.Accepted:
            results = dialog.get_values()
            for i in (3, 4):
                k = rec.fieldName(i)
                results[k] = results[k].toString("yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm")
            for k, value in results.items():
                rec.setValue(k, value)
            self.db_model.insertRecord(-1, rec)
            self.db_model.select()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(-1)
    w = Widget()
    w.resize(960, 480)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```